# Determining HTML element visibility server side

Tags: asp.net, css

If a HTML element such as an input box is hidden under a CSS visibility e.g. Display:None.  Can I determine server-side whether this element is hidden of not.  And if so, how?

Comment: for some reason I am thinking this could be used to counter the spam bot checks using css hidden inputs? Hmmm...  is that the intent?

Comment: No, the intent is as follows.  Given a form with a repeating group of information, e.g. An address.  I control the visibility of the repeating group with another control (e.g a yes/no radio button). If the repeating group is visible I want to be able to determine this to determine whether or not to persist any data entered. If the user hides the repeating group. I want to ignore any data entered.  I dont want to inspect the radio button  status as I dont have any knowledge of the relationship between the radio button and repeating group server side (rules are all emitted in JSON/Jquery)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no, you cannot".

The long answer is: if you are absolutely sure that this element visibility can only be altered via CSS you could parse all applicable CSS files. It's rather hard but possible.

However, in real life you also need to know the exact browser version (due to possible CSS hacks and thus difference in behavior) plus quite often element visibility is toggled via javascript.

**Update** (based on OP's clarification):
I would strongly suggest using a hidden field (`<input type="hidden">`) in order to determine visibility as you've described. Hidden field value can be changed via javascript as radio group value changes.

Comment: Coincidentally, mooted this with a few other peeps. Without going into too much detail this is probably the only way I can achieve what I am looking for WITHOUT caring about the relationship between the radio button and repeating group server side (would require a tweak to the framework I am currently working with). Thanks for your time..